# Getting this error as soon as I use Using System; in vb.net statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net as code behind. As soon as I added USING System; I started getting error.
Here is what I have, its literally nothing except the basic structure.

```
using system;
Public Class Appointment

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    Me.Load
    End Sub
    Public Function saveAppointment() As String
        Return 0
    End Function
End Class
```

In aspx I have this in header

I am unable to understand the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.net does not have the `using xyzNamespace;` syntax (that is C# syntax). Also, don't forget that VB.Net doesn't use semicolon ";" as a line terminator either.

You should do `Imports System` instead

Comment: @user2165764 if it helped, then click the checkmark next to the answer to indicate so (and earn some rep)